# Anyone know what these NPM warnings are about

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-link

I get these warnings after running "npm install" in my project or "npm link" in a project that depends on it.

```
android-96cfb953347b915b:suman t_millal$ npm link
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/bl/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/commoner/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/fsevents/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/http-signature/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/bl/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/commoner/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/fsevents/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/t_millal/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman-server/node_modules/http-signature/package.json'
npm WARN babel-loader@6.2.5 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta but none was installed.
```

Comment: Err, don't they mean you're missing files `npm` is expecting to find?

Comment: Sure but any other insights?

Comment: That's a warning that I see if I have directories under `node_modules` that don't contain a `package.json` and don't correspond to dependencies in the the project's `package.json`.

Comment: maybe that's true, but that doesn't make sense, why would NPM go looking for something it wasn't supposed to be looking for?

Comment: I wonder if "npm uninstall x y z" will solve the problem?

Comment: Weird that "'.../node_modules/bl/package.json'" and "'.../node_modules/commoner/package.json'" are listed twice....that's a clue...